# AWS Pricing with S3, CloudFront, Route 53, and SSL?

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have a small static website <2mb (free storage in Amazon S3...?) that we want to host in an Amazon S3 bucket and distribute using CloudFront.

Approx. 4 million sessions per month, where each session might be max. 250 GET requests.

Looking at CloudFront (US West/US East 60%, Europe 35%, Australia 5%).

There are 4 domains that need to use this single AngularJS website app (region-based domains). But we only need to use a sub-domain for this app. Does that mean we can skip using Route 53, and just point the sub-domain at CloudFront?

Need to serve through HTTPS and SSL. Do we need CloudFront Custom SSL, and if so, do we need to purchase a Custom SSL for each domain?

If I'm paying for Bandwidth/Requests for CloudFront, am I paying that again for Amazon S3?

What would be an estimate price for us to host for a month with all our needs?

Comment: Contact Amazon support - they have solutions architects that are paid to do exactly this sort of thing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better addressed to the vendor.  Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

On AWS there is a tool that were made to do exactly this calculation.
It will also help to calculate all the necessary cost based on your needs.

Here is the link
http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

When you do the calculation, you will see that amazon is not that expensive.

I hope this will help you!

Comment: If the bandwidth is taken from cloudfront you won't be paying bandwidth for S3 because the bandwidth is coming from cloudfront. Basically, it will result in less bandwidth/requests on your S3. You will need SSL, you can buy one ssl that contains multiple domains.

Comment: Maybe submit a support request if you have pricing issues?